# How can I edit an offline .geodatabase file with ArcGIS SDK for Android?

Tags: android, offline, arcgis

I´m trying to edit an offline `.geodatabase` file using the ArcGIS SDK for Android. I've been looking in the documentation and I've found the way using services but my app doesn't use any services, just an offline file.

What I'm doing is open the `.geodatabase` file, when file opens it creates automatically two files (.geodatabase-shm, .geodatabase-wal). Later, when I want to edit the information relative to a cell of the map, I call the method:

```
GeodatabaseFeatureTable.updateFeature(long featureId, Map<String, Object> attributes)
```

And the files (.geodatabase-shm, .geodatabase-wal) are updated but not the original (.geodatabase).

I need to send the file .geodatabase to a server for other users to download it, so how can I apply the changes to this file? Are there some geodatabase transactions that I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files .geodatabase-shm and .geodatabase-wal are temporary files and the changes will be applied to the original .geodatabase when it will be closed.

So, the solution consists of calling method `Geodatabase.close()` when geodatabase is no longer in use, for instance in onDestroy method. Here is the method overview: [Geodatabase close method](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/data/Geodatabase.html#close())

In my case I have to use a different method because I´m maybe using an older version of ArcGIS SDK. The method is `Geodatabase.dispose()`, and you can see description here: [Geodatabase dispose method](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/Geodatabase.html)